# How to write macro for OpenOffice Writer to remove all index markerkers

Tags: openoffice-writer, openoffice-basic

OpenOffice Writer Index builder is very useful, but has some problems. For example even if terms are removed from the concordance file and a document is re-indexed the removed terms remain indexed. A macro can be written for Microsoft Word to remove all index marks, for example [https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=106555]

Unfortunately going back and forth between Writer and Word creates problems with complex documents. How can a similar macro be written for OpenOffice Writer? Word displays indexed terms if CTRL - SHIFT - 8 is pressed and then the indexing can be manually removed. How can indexed terms by displayed and edited in Writer?

Answer (score 0):

Open Office and Libre Office .odt files are .zip files.

If renamed with .zip suffix the actual content fie is obtained as content.xml.

A script can be written to remove xml statements setting index marks.

Found the LibreOffice generated xml file simpler to process and once the .odt is re-zipped with the processed content.xml file the index marks disappear and there are less problems than with the OpenOffice version.file.